# How to install apache-airflow and apache-beam together using Docker or Docker-compose?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, airflow, apache-beam

I would like to **install apache airflow and apache beam together using either Docker or Docker-Compose**.
What I'm trying to accomplish is: Currently, I've apache airflow DAGS with different tasks and in one of the task I want to incorporate/ integrate apache beam data pipeline. And In order to run this workflow successfully I need to install the apache beam dependency. For example: **pip install apache-beam** and **pip install apache-beam[gcp]**

Currently, I'm using Puckel Docker image for apache airflow. My preferences are:
1. https://github.com/apache/airflow
2. https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow

I want to go with the first link as its an official image. If anyone has solution with puckel docker image then please help me to understand how can I get the latest changes everytime from the repository.

I'm new to docker, apache-airflow and apache-beam. I'm learning and growing slowly. So, your help is much appreciated. Thank you so much!!! :)

Comment: Do you have some parts, like the start of a `Dockerfile` or a `docker-compose.yml` file, that you need help debugging?  What work have you done already?

Comment: There is currently an ongoing effort in Airflow to introduce the [new official multi-layered Docker image](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-10+Multi-layered+and+multi-stage+official+Airflow+image), which from what I know should be completed very soon. You might want to take a look at that as it might replace the puckel image used by many people currently.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze for responding.
Actually I don't want to proceed with Puckel docker image. I'm looking for an official docker image which I can modify according to needs like installing the packages like apache beam.

Comment: Thank you @SzymonPrzedwojski for your valuable feedback.

Comment: @DavidMaze
Here is the docker-compose.yml file contents.
<https://pastebin.com/NEqtg156>